# Efficiently testing if every member of a sublist comes before every other member of another sublist

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of elements -

```
bigList = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
```

And two sublists:

```
sublistOne = {"H", "B", "D"};
sublistTwo = {"I", "L", "J"};
```

How do I efficiently create a function `f` that returns `TRUE` only if all elements of `sublistOne` come before all elements of `sublistTwo` in `bigList`?

For the provided example, `f` should return `TRUE`.  However, if we kept the same `sublistOne` and set `sublistTwo = {"I", "F", J"}`, `f` should return false because element `F` in `sublistTwo` appears prior to element `H` in sublistOne.

Please note that I could scramble the English alphabet in `bigList` and then have the first example return `FALSE`.  The function `f` should only test the index of each variable and ignore its numeric or string value.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Position` to extract the positions of the elements in `bigList`. Then, you only need to ensure that the biggest position number in the `sublistOne` is smaller than the smallest position number in `sublistTwo`

```
f[big_, s1_, s2_] := Max[#1] < Min[#2] & @@ (Position[big, Alternatives[##]] & @@@ {s1, s2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
And @@ MapThread[
  Cases[bigList, Alternatives[##], 1, 1] =!= {#2} &,
  {sublistOne, sublistTwo}]
```

As a function, which bails out at the first unordered pair:

```
ordQ[ordering_, list1_, list2_] := Catch[
  MapThread[
   If[Cases[ordering, Alternatives[##], 1, 1] === {#2}, 
     Throw[False]] &,
   {list1, list2}];
  True]

ordQ[bigList, sublistOne, sublistTwo]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using two new-in-Version-10 variations:

`FirstPosition`:

```
pF1=With[{p=FirstPosition[Alternatives@@#]&/@{#1,#2}},
         First[Length[#3]-p[[1]]@Reverse@#3]<First[p[[2]]@#3]]&;
pF1[sublistOne,sublistTwo,bigList]
(* True *)
```

Operator form of `Position`:

```
pF2=With[{p=Position[Alternatives@@#]&/@{#1,#2}},   Max[p[[1]]@#3]<Min[p[[2]]@#3]]&;
pF2[sublistOne,sublistTwo,bigList]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I could scramble the English alphabet ... The function f should only test the index of each variable and ignore its numeric or string value.

This task is a natural fit for `PositionIndex` but not as much for `Interval`, although I will try to stretch it a bit as it allows for visualization using `NumberLinePlot`.

```
bigList = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L",
    "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", 
   "Z"};
pi = PositionIndex[bigList];

sublist1 = {"H", "B", "D"};
sublist2 = {"I", "L", "J"};
sublist3 = {"I", "F", "J"};
```

Define a function that determines the `Interval` using the position index called `pi`:

```
f[k_List] := Interval[MinMax[k /. pi // Flatten]]

{f@sublist1, f@sublist2, IntervalIntersection[f@sublist1, f@sublist2]}
```

> {Interval[{2, 8}], Interval[{9, 12}], Interval[]}

For visualization:

```
ticks = Transpose[{Sequence @@@ Values@pi, Keys@pi}]
NumberLinePlot[{
  Values@pi, f@sublist1, f@sublist2
  , IntervalIntersection[f@sublist1, f@sublist2]
  }
 , Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}
 ]
```

[image]

With `sublist3`:

```
{f@sublist1, f@sublist3, IntervalIntersection[f@sublist1, f@sublist3]}
```

> {Interval[{2, 8}], Interval[{6, 10}], Interval[{6, 8}]}

[image]

---

Now let's scramble the `bigList`:

```
SeedRandom[2];
newBigList = RandomSample[bigList, 26]
pi = PositionIndex[newBigList];
s1 = Characters@"CUZ";
s2 = Characters@"ICAN";
{f[s1], f[s2], IntervalIntersection[f[s1], f[s2]]}
```

> {Interval[{24, 26}], Interval[{7, 24}], Interval[{24, 24}]}

```
ticks = Transpose[{Sequence @@@ Values@pi, Keys@pi}]
NumberLinePlot[{
  Values@pi, f@s1, f@s2, IntervalIntersection[f[s1], f[s2]]
  }
 , Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}
 ]
```

[image]